# How to Enable dragging files on custom application on launcher?

Tags: unity, mime-type

In unity, we can drag files on application's button in the launcher to open that file with that application - however, looks like its hard to change default application.

I use Komodo as editor, and my goal is to open php files dragging on the Komodo button on the launcher.

The problem is that with gtk3 is a bit tricky to add custom application to open mimetypes..

I've created the button from the Main Menu, then i user `mimeopen -d file.php` to set komodo as default; Now, if i double-click on a php file, it get open with komodo - but I cant drag php files on komodo button on launcher.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is editing the `.desktop` file of your application launcher.
Browse for Komodo in `/usr/share/applications/` and open it with your favourite text editor running as root (e.g. type sudo gedit on the terminal).

What you have to focus on is the `MimeType=` part (add it if it doesn't exist): add `application/x-php` to the key, **wich will let you drag and drop PHP files to Komodo**, and then save the `.desktop` file.

- For instance, your *MimeType* key should look like this: `MimeType=text/plain;application/x-php;`

---

More information about *Desktop Entry Files* syntax [here](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en). A full list of Mime Types and their corresponding suffixes [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full).

Comment: For DnD onto a launcher icon you must have a `MimeType=` line in the .desktop that lists the type(s) you wish to be able to DnD

Comment: You are right. I've edited the post ;)

Comment: First link is dead/403, and I can't find that info in the current set of pages.

Comment: @Christoph Updated the link to the current verion on GNOME's web.